# How to specify dependencies for your python code

Tags: python

I am working in a team and wrote some python code that uses libraries that need to be installed separately (because they are not part of standard python distribution). How should I specify those ? What is the right/correct/pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Provide an installation package?

Comment: @wallyk Well I don't know what you mean exactly. I specified what I want exactly in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally use `pip install -r requirements.txt`
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files

Answer (score 5):

Check out tool called `pip`. It's what most python projects use these days.

Typically, one would do the following (for example, we want to install the `requests` package for our new project):

```
pip install requests
```

and then

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Now, we have installed `requests` on our system and saved the dependency version to a file which we can distribute with our project.

At this point, `requirements.txt` contains:

```
requests==2.7.0
```

To install the same set of requirements (in our case only the `requests` package) on some other system, one would do the following:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to make a `setup.py` file for your package that specifies required packages. You may need to reorganize your file structure and include data and a manifest.
2. Then create a distribution of your package, EG: a wheel file.
3. Then when using `pip install your_package_distro.whl`, pip will determine your packages dependencies are met and install them from PyPI unless you specify another package source (EG: https://pypi.anaconda.org/)

Read through the following references to distribute your code:

- [Python 2.7.10 documentation - Distributing Python Modules, Section 2: Writing the Setup Script](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html)
- [Setuptools - Building and Distributing Packages with Setuptools](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html)
- [Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [Hitchhiker's Guide to Python - Packaging your Code](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/packaging/)